# How to query 2 relational tables for private messaging inbox

Tags: mysql

I would appreciate some help/guidance on my attempt to create a private messaging system and formulate some sql statements.
I have two tables

Messages: id(key), recipient_id, sender_id, subject, message, read_status, recipient_delete, sender_delete, sent_date

Replies: id(key), message_id(same as id in messages), message, sender_id, recipient_id, read_status, sender_delete, recipient_delete, sent_date

I am trying to create an inbox similar to an email inbox where latest messages received appear at the top. That's pretty easy enough to query messages and return all message for specific user and sorted by sent_date.

The issue: I need to also query the replies table so that the inbox items are sorted not only by sent_date of messages but also replies.

Thus, in the inbox user will see all parent messages sorted by date but if there is new reply for a particular message that will be at the top etc. I hope I am making myself clear.

Kindly help me with formulating the correct sql statement to achieve the outcome as above.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should create only 1 table with the following:

> id, recipient_id, sender_id, message_id, subject, message,
>   read_status, recipient_delete, sender_delete, sent_date

On a new message you simply intert with message_id null

On a reply you attache the main message id

Then you have only one table to select

Here's a starting point for you. Modify the querys as needed.

Asumin:
sender id is 1 (ME)
recipient id is 2 (YOU)
message id is 3 (US)

To get the inbox of received messages

```
SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE recipient_id='2' and message_id IS NULL order by id desc
```

To get the inbox of send messages

```
SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE sender_id='2' and message_id IS NULL order by id desc
```

To get the all messages

```
SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE (recipient_id='2' or sender_id='1') and message_id IS NULL order by id desc
```

To get the messages with replys

```
SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE (message_id='3' and (recipient_id='2' or sender_id='1')) or id='3' order by id desc
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. But im confused! In your statement to get messages with replies, why do you say message_id=3? Also, will get all messages show messages and replies as separate rows? Im thinking if email inbox style rows.

Comment: For inbox i need to show parent messages sorted by latest including if there is reply. This is the bit where I am having difficulty

Comment: When you clic on a message, you wana display the message with all the replys order to read the email right? So the message you clicked is id='3'. The replys can be found with message_id='3' The SQL are just exemples. You can play with them as you need. My point is you should have only one table not 2.

Comment: Again thanks, but how then does the original sender know if there is a reply? In his inbox, it wont show because of the null. How do i then select so the original message will show again in his inbox but when he clicks on it, of course he will see the reply. That is why i had two tables.